# How soon are S4 methods loaded upon package load?

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm working with a R package where a `S4` object defined in that package is created in the `.onLoad` hook. It turns out that the `initialize` method defined for its super class is not run but rather then generic `initialize` defined for `ANY` object.

I've been poking around and I cannot see if:

- there is a way to load (register) these methods faster when the package is loaded
- this is an error and the methods shouold be there already when `.onLoad` is run

I'm also trying to find information about how soon these methods should be loaded/registered when a given package is loaded for the first time. I'll be very grateful for pointer to such information/documentation.

**Update:**

Here is a sample package that demonstrates my problem. If you build it and load it, and then run `verifyS4Initialization()`, you will see that the object created from within `.onLoad()` is not initialized while the one created after the package is fully loaded is initialized according to the `initialize` method.

https://github.com/lbartnik/s4load

Comment: Include your `.onLoad` code in your question.

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/lbartnik/s4load